# How can I output powers to a user?

Tags: python, math, output, show

I'm doing a maths revision program and I want to print out a question with y to the power of x(like `xⁿ`). I can't find a way to print it out as this form. Has anyone got any ideas?

[This is how I want it to be displayed.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MW8Uq.png)

Comment: Print to terminal?

Comment: You mean like this? `xⁿ`

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I want.

Answer (score 0):

One possible option using [ANSI escape sequences](http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences.php), it is not possible to control font size:

```
base = "x"
exponent = "n"

print('\033[1BFormula = %s\033[1A%s\033[1B etcetera'%(exponent, base))
```

In terminal you get:

```
 #            x
 #Formula = n   etcetera
```

Comment: No that didn't seem to work

Comment: @tegan.joy try `print('{}\033[1A{}\033[1B'.format(base, exponent))`